# I got error when ı set up docker with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to set up docker container in my django app. But I failed when ı building docker. Can you help me or share some resources? how can fix problem. I used docker-compose build. Most probably requirements.txt not work well. I applied some logic but they did not work.[image: Folder structure]

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install python3-dev build-essential -y

#pip requirements

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install virtualenv && python -m virtualenv venv

ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN pip install django


COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


COPY . /srv/app
WORKDIR /srv/app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:7000
```

log

```
 => [app  7/10] COPY ./requirements.txt .                                                                             0.1s 
 => ERROR [app  8/10] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                             37.6s 
------
 > [app  8/10] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt:
3.098 Requirement already satisfied: asgiref==3.7.2 in /venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.7.2)
3.099 Requirement already satisfied: Django==4.2.3 in /venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (4.2.3)
3.442 Collecting django-environ==0.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
3.785   Downloading django_environ-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
4.632 Collecting djangorestframework==3.14.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
4.747   Downloading djangorestframework-3.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
27.98      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.1/1.1 MB 45.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
28.78 Collecting psycopg2==2.9.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
28.90   Downloading psycopg2-2.9.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
36.10      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 384.0/384.0 kB 54.2 kB/s eta 0:00:00
36.17   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
36.99   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
37.00   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
37.00
37.00   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
37.00   │ exit code: 1
37.00   ╰─> [37 lines of output]
37.00       /venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
37.00       !!
37.00
37.00               ********************************************************************************
37.00               The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
37.00
37.00               By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
37.00               or your builds will no longer be supported.
37.00
37.00               See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
37.00               ********************************************************************************
37.00
37.00       !!
37.00         parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
37.00       running egg_info
37.00       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-jt1u5ugs/psycopg2.egg-info
37.00       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-jt1u5ugs/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
37.00       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-jt1u5ugs/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
37.00       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-jt1u5ugs/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
37.00       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-jt1u5ugs/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
37.00
37.00       Error: pg_config executable not found.
37.00
37.00       pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
37.00       containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
37.00       option:
37.00
37.00           python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
37.00
37.00       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
37.00
37.00       If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
37.00       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
37.00
37.00       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
37.00       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
37.00
37.00       [end of output]
37.00
37.00   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
37.01 error: metadata-generation-failed
37.01
37.01 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
37.01 ╰─> See above for output.
37.01
37.01 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
37.01 hint: See above for details.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the requirements.txt you are installing a PostgreSQL dependent extension. So, you need to install PostgreSQL binaries that contains `pg_config` and then in your dockerile you need to extend you `PATH` variable like this;

```
ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH_2_pg_config:$PATH"
```